# Per App setting for 'Use font smoothing when available'?

Tags: settings, preferences, defaults

> Historically this setting (System Preferences -> General) controls
>   subpixel font anti-aliasing.
>
> Since Mojave deprecates subpixel rendering, it controls how much
>   greyscale anti-aliasing is applied. That is, the text looks more bold
>   when this is checked.

Is it possible to tweak this setting per app (`defaults write` stuff), especially for the menu bar?